# Stop company-mode from completing dictionary words

Tags: company-mode

How can I stop company-mode from autocompleting dictionary words? I only want it to autocomplete commands.

This is my config:

```
(use-package company
  :ensure
  :defer 4
  :init (progn
          (global-company-mode)
          (setq company-global-modes '(not python-mode cython-mode sage-mode))
          )
  :config (progn
            (setq company-tooltip-limit 20
                  company-idle-delay .1
                  company-echo-delay 0
                  company-begin-commands '(self-insert-command)
                  company-transformers '(company-sort-by-occurrence)
                  company-selection-wrap-around t
                  company-idle-delay .1
                  company-minimum-prefix-length 1
                  company-selection-wrap-around t
                  company-dabbrev-downcase nil
                  )
            (bind-keys :map company-active-map
                       ("C-n" . company-select-next)
                       ("C-p" . company-select-previous)
                       ("C-d" . company-show-doc-buffer)
                       ("<tab>" . company-complete)
                       ("<escape>" . company-abort)
                       )
            )
  )
```

**UPDATE:**
I just noticed that it autocompletes not from the dictionary (ispell) but from all words already existing in the current buffer. How can I stop it from doing so?

Comment: Check the value of the variable `company-backends`, do you see `company-dabbrev` in the list of backends for the major mode you are using ? If so, try to remove `company-dabbrev` from `company-backends` and let me know if it works for you

Comment: `company-keywords` is the backend which complete default keywords from dictionary file.

Comment: I had the same problem, company keeps on automatically committing the 1st candidate word as soon as I typed enough number of characters according to `company-minimum-prefix-length`. I ended up removing the `company` from the melpa channel and installing that from the `gnu` channel instead, and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take a look at the variable `company-backends`.

If you append the backends you want to use manually, the preconfigured backends will be ignored.

So if you want to only complete python commands, you'd have to use 
`(add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-jedi))`

You should configure your backends for every mode that uses company.

Of course you have to install jedi first.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do: 
`(delete 'company-dabbrev company-backends)
            (delete '(company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords) company-backends)
(add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-auctex)
`

Comment: This is weird. It shouldn't be necessary to delete those backends.

Comment: Yeap, I tried only with the `add-to-list` command, but the other backends were still there...

Comment: did you only check the value of the variable or have you really tested the functionality?

Comment: I checked the value, before and after.